# Specifying a task-dependency in a rake rule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a rake rule transforming files that also needs to depend on the :environment (meta-)task. However, I keep running into errors. The rule looks as follows:

```
task :parse => SOURCE_FILES.ext(".md")
rule ".md" => ->(f){ source_for_md(f) } do |t|
  `do stuff ${t.source}`
end
```

I have tried `rule ".md" => [:environment, ->(f){ source_for_md(f)] }`

which results in the error:

```
Don't know how to handle rule dependent: :environment
```

I have also tried to define the depency upstream in the :parse task:

```
task parse: [:environment, SOURCE_FILES.ext(".md")]
```

... with no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rake rule with task dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324943/rake-rule-with-task-dependency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround that is only slightly inelegant: moving the dependency a further level up in the chain works:

```
task do_parse: [:environment, :parse]
task :parse => SOURCE_FILES.ext(".md")
rule ".md" => ->(f){ source_for_md(f) } do |t|
  `do stuff ${t.source}`
end
```