# Rake rule with task dependency

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm trying to make a rake rule that depends on another task. It works if I only use tasks as shown below:

```
task :foo do
  @iv = 42
end

task :bar => :foo do
  p @iv
end

Rake::Task[:bar].invoke
```

result:

```
42
```

I'd like to be able to use rules so I can use regexes. But I'm getting an error:

```
task :foo do
  @iv = 42
end

rule /bar/ => :foo do
  p @iv
end

Rake::Task["bar"].invoke
```

result:

```
/Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:284:in `block in make_sources': Don't know how to handle rule dependent: :foo (RuntimeError)
  from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:267:in `map'
  from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:267:in `make_sources'
  from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:245:in `attempt_rule'
  from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:130:in `block in enhance_with_matching_rule'
  from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:128:in `each'
  from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:128:in `enhance_with_matching_rule'
  from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:56:in `[]'
  from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:361:in `[]'
  from baz.rb:63:in `<main>'
```

How do I use a rule that depends on another task?

Edit:

As mentioned below the rule takes it's dependency as a string:

```
task :foo do
  @iv = 42
end

rule /bar/ => "foo" do
  p @iv
end

Rake::Task["bar"].invoke
#=> 42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `:foo` to `"foo"` solves the problem.

It seems `task_manager.rb#make_sources` does not handle symbols.

https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/task_manager.rb#L266,L288